# Delete Using Open Query with Join Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I delete using SQL OPENQUERY with join statement

This is my code.. what is wrong with this?

```
delete from 
OPENQUERY(LINKSERVERNAME, 'SELECT Z.* from Project1.dbo.table1 Z') A
left join Project2.dbo.Table2 B on A.ID = B.ID
where B.ID is null
```

Project1 Database is within an online sql Server
Project2 Database is within my local sql Server

thanks

Comment: You will delete all rows from all joined tables ? :=) But I don't know anything about OPenQuery... But you need to specify the table where you want to be records deleted when using joins

Comment: yes Laurent Lequenne, I will delete all rows from online server with null values from my local Server..

Comment: Good for you :=) But what is your error message ?

Comment: It's just my query is not right.. I cant delete the records while im using join

Comment: try  : delete Z from .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
DELETE FROM A
FROM OPENQUERY([LINKSERVERNAME], 'SELECT Z.* from Project1.dbo.table1 Z') A
LEFT JOIN Project2.dbo.Table2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID is null
```